# Node server on docker not accessible on localhost even after port binding

Tags: node.js, docker, localhost, graphql

I have graphql node server. I am able to run it locally without docker. But after creating a docker container of the server and binding the container port with the host port this doesn't work.

Here's my Dockerfile code:

```
 FROM node:boron-alpine
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY package.json /app
 RUN npm install
 COPY . /app
 ENV SERVER_PORT 8080 
 EXPOSE 8080
 CMD npm run build && npm start
```

My node server code is as such :

```
  app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT,'0.0.0.0')
  console.log(`listening at ${port}`)
```

I run docker with the following command:

```
   docker run -it -p 8080:8080  nodeapi
```

This works perfectly nodejs can see the env SERVER_PORT cause it shows

```
   "listening at 8080"
```

in the console.

But when i open localhost:8080 this doesn't work (The site cannot be reached).

I have also tried running docker command

```
    docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080  nodeapi
```

This doesn't work

I am using docker toolbox on windows 10 latest build

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Docker toolbox doesn't map ports to localhost. It maps it to the Docker VM IP's

Run below command to get the IP

```
docker-machine ip
```

Then use the `http://<IP>:8080` in your browser

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. But is there a way to map it to localhost instead?.

Comment: docker-machine ip gives  No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exist to me

Comment: @scroobius, you can map it to localhost by doing port forwarding in the VM settings

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, you are using docker for windows or docker toolbox? You can manually launch virtualbox and see the machine name. If there is none then that means you haven't initialised the default machine as well

Answer (score 6):

If you avoid specifying the IP 0.0.0.0

```
app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, function () {
   console.log('Listening on port '+ process.env.SERVER_PORT);
});
```

and

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080  nodeapi
```

it will let you load the site as

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

when you start the Docker using docker quickstart terminal, you can see the IP Address. (you can get to know the ip-address using the command "docker-machine ip" as well)

URL to access will be http://ip-address:portbinded